# Remove 'u' from json data using Python

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, amazon-sqs

I have a Python code which basically extracts the data from Amazon SQS, I need to index this JSON data to Elasticsearch. Currently my code looks like:

```
import os
import json
import uuid
import time
import boto.sqs
import boto
from boto.sqs.connection import SQSConnection
from boto.sqs.message import Message
from boto.sqs.message import RawMessage
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
import ast

parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('/home/ubuntu/config.ini')

#get details via config file

region = parser.get('default', 'aws_region')
access_key = parser.get('default', 'aws_access_key')
secret_key = parser.get('default', 'aws_secret_key')
queue_name = parser.get('default', 'sqs_queue_name')

sqs = boto.sqs.connect_to_region(region,aws_access_key_id=access_key,aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
q = sqs.get_queue(queue_name) #SQS queue name

m = q.read(visibility_timeout=15)
if m == None:
  print "No message!"
else:
    a = m.get_body()
    print a
    print type(a)

    new_list = json.loads(a)
    print new_list
    print type(new_list)
```

This produces a result as :

```
{
    "facter": {
        "blockdevice_xvda_size": 8589934592,
        "blockdevices": "xvda,xvdb",
        "fqdn": "ip-1-12-5-9.us-west-2.compute.internal",
        "hardwaremodel": "x86_64",
        "hostname": "ip-1-12-5-9",
        "instanceid": "i-a54d7c",
        "ipaddress": "1.12.5.9",
        "is_virtual": "true",
        "kernelrelease": "3.13.0-48-generic",
        "lsbdistcodename": "trusty",
        "lsbdistdescription": "Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS",
        "macaddress": "2:00:a:66:61:4f",
        "memoryfree": "3.56 GB",
        "memorytotal": "3.68 GB",
        "netmask": "255.255.255.12",
        "operatingsystem": "Ubuntu",
        "operatingsystemrelease": "14.04",
        "processor0": "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz",
        "processorcount": "1",
        "timezone": "UTC",
        "uniqueid": "660a4f41",
        "uptime": "23:36 hours"
    }
}
<type 'unicode'>
{u'facter': {u'kernelrelease': u'3.13.0-48-generic', u'memoryfree': u'3.56 GB', u'memorytotal': u'3.68 GB', u'processorcount': u'1', u'timezone': u'UTC', u'operatingsystem': u'Ubuntu', u'uptime': u'23:36 hours', u'hostname': u'ip-1-12-5-9', u'is_virtual': u'true', u'blockdevices': u'xvda,xvdb', u'hardwaremodel': u'x86_64', u'netmask': u'255.255.255.192', u'blockdevice_xvda_size': 8589934592, u'uniqueid': u'660a4f41', u'ipaddress': u'10.102.65.79', u'lsbdistdescription': u'Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS', u'macaddress': u'2:00:a:66:41:4f', u'operatingsystemrelease': u'14.04', u'processor0': u'Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz', u'instanceid': u'i-a54d7c', u'fqdn': u'ip-1-12-5-9.us-west-2.compute.internal', u'lsbdistcodename': u'trusty'}}
<type 'dict'>
```

As you can see that its a dictionary having unicode. I need to extract "instanceid" from this dictionary and use it index it in ES. I am stuck on how to extract the index id. I tried:

```
 ast.literal_eval(json.dumps())
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is quite literally *nothing to do* here.

Comment: As others said, that `u` won't harm anything. It's there to denote that the strings are unicode strings. When yo'll use any `dict` element, that `u` won't be involved in any operation you'll do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `new_list` is a `dict` you should be able to just extract that with a simple

```
instanceid = new_list['facter']['instanceid']
```

The `u` you see before your strings are just telling you that the strings are unicode strings, and not a "C-string".
In your case it doesn't matter, since there are no unicode characters in any of the dictionary keys.